# Installing OpenFOAM 2.3 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apt, 14.04

There is currently no package for Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty at http://www.openfoam.org/download/ubuntu.php.  If I try to use the package for 13.10 Saucy `aptitude` gives me an error when I try

```
sudo aptitude install openfoam230 paraviewopenfoam410
```

[snipped long list of dependencies]

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openfoam230 : Depends: libboost-thread1.53.0 which is a virtual package.
               Depends: libopenmpi1.3 which is a virtual package.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     openfoam230 [Not Installed]
```

Until an official package becomes available, is there a way around this without installing from source?

Comment: this should solve the unmet issue 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenFoam can be installed by apt-get now.. see http://www.openfoam.org/download/ubuntu.php

Answer (score 2):

you have to wait until they release trusty version (14.04) if you want to use apt, otherwise you can compile the source file. Look at this link for instructions:
http://www.openfoam.org/download/source.php

This link also provides information for installing from source file
http://openfoamwiki.net/index.php/Installation/Linux/OpenFOAM-2.3.0/Ubuntu#Ubuntu_14.04

Comment: Sure, but I was hoping to avoid the build time of around 0.5 -- 6 hours :)

Comment: Ï  am trying to install too, but I found these instructions on the page: http://www.openfoam.org/download/ubuntu.php My trouble is what to do with `VERS=$`. Should I write `VERS=precise` or simple `precise` instead of `VERS=$`???